# Adding typing for module which exports instance of some class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write .d.ts file for foo-foo-mq module but can't use them

As it described in docs I've created folder 'foo-foo-mq' inside my 'typings' folder in the root of the project. Then I've created index.d.ts file with this:

```ts
declare module 'foo-foo-mq' {

  function configure(options: TopologyOptions): { done: (callback: () => void) => void };

  export enum TopologyExchangeType { FANOUT = 'fanout', TOPIC = 'topic', DIRECT = 'direct' }

  export interface TopologyExchange {
    name: string;
    type: TopologyExchangeType;
    autoDelete?: boolean;
    publishTimeout?: number;
    alternate?: string;
    persistent?: boolean;
  }

  export interface TopologyQueue {
    name: string;
    autoDelete: boolean;
    subscribe: boolean;
    queueLimit?: number;
    limit?: number;
    deadLetter?: string;
  }

  export interface TopologyBinding {
    exchange: string;
    target: string;
    keys: Array<string>
  }

  export interface TopologyOptions {
    connection: {
      name?: string;
      user?: string;
      pass?: string;
      host?: string | string[];
      port?: number;
      timeout?: number;
      vhost?: string;
      replyQueue?: string;
    },
    exchanges?: TopologyExchange[];
    queues?: TopologyQueue[],
    bindings?: TopologyBinding[]
  }
}
```

Now I can use it and everything looks fine:

```ts
import rabbit from 'foo-foo-mq'

rabbit.configure()
```

But if I want to assign rabbit to some private property I can't figure out which type i have to specify for this variable:

i.e:

```ts
class SomeHiLevelClass {
   constructor(private rabbit:????) {}
}
```

Ive checked sources of foo-foo-mq and Ive found this (simplified):

```js
class Broker { ... }
module.exports  = new Broker()
```

So, it's exporting instance of Broker class. Is there any way to describe this in d.ts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made actual ts file, transpiled it and looked into .d.ts to understand how to do this. And here is solution:

```ts
declare module 'foo-foo-mq' {

  export enum TopologyExchangeType { FANOUT = 'fanout', TOPIC = 'topic', DIRECT = 'direct' }

  export interface TopologyExchange {
    name: string;
    type: TopologyExchangeType;
    autoDelete?: boolean;
    publishTimeout?: number;
    alternate?: string;
    persistent?: boolean;
  }

  export interface TopologyQueue {
    name: string;
    autoDelete: boolean;
    subscribe: boolean;
    queueLimit?: number;
    limit?: number;
    deadLetter?: string;
  }

  export interface TopologyBinding {
    exchange: string;
    target: string;
    keys: Array<string>
  }

  export interface TopologyOptions {
    connection: {
      name?: string;
      user?: string;
      pass?: string;
      host?: string | string[];
      port?: number;
      timeout?: number;
      vhost?: string;
      replyQueue?: string;
    },
    exchanges?: TopologyExchange[];
    queues?: TopologyQueue[],
    bindings?: TopologyBinding[]
  }

  export class Broker {
    configure(options: TopologyOptions): Promise<void>;
  }

  const _default: Broker

  export default _default;
}
```

So, now I can do:

```ts
import rabbit, { Broker } from 'foo-foo-mq'
...
constructor(private rabbit: Broker ) {}
...
rabbit.configure()
```